# Unable to run the perl script from the server machine

Tags: java, perl

```
        String name="perl http://10.107.97.201//C:/KATool/code/names.pl ";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(name);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

I am unable to run the perl script from the server machine .. and above is the server ip( dummy) which is mentione in the application.
Please help me in this..
And thanks in Advance..

Comment: This is the Error message I am getting when i m invoking the perl script                                                              "Can't open perl script "perl 10.107.97.201//C:/KATool/code/names.pl ":

Answer (score 2):

perl deals with filesystems, not internet protocols, so when you give perl "http://..." its like you gave notepad "http://...", it does not compute

So to run names.pl locally, first you have to download it (wget ...), then run it

Comment: Hey Donk, I am able to run the names.pl in my location machine quite perfectly.And the same names.pl while running from other machines ( by making my local machine as server to other machine)its giving Can't open perl script "perl 10.107.97.201//C:/KATool/code/names.pl ": error...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to remote machine? Can you run this line from your terminal:

```
perl http://10.107.97.201//C:/KATool/code/names.pl
```

Run this in your terminal and investigate the error message you got. Maybe **perl script itself is broken**, or just you don't have (or you lost) access to remote machine.

Comment: Hi Samet...Ya i have the remote access to my server and i can able to run the script in my server also.. bt when i m trying to invoke from my client machine its giving some "Can't open perl script "perl http://10.107.97.201//C:/KATool/code/names.pl 
": Invalid argument"

Comment: Run perl script from terminal in your client machine and post the error message here.

Comment: The purpose of the perl script is to display the names in a sorting order.... and this is the output of the names.pl in my client after running from the treminal.. i can get the o/p in client machine.. bt while accesing from the server machine i am nt geeting the same output.. and istead of it.. its showing some Inavlid arument error messgae.. which is stated in the above coment                                                               names.pl in client machine output :Mrs Smith
Mr Jones
Ms Samuel
Dr Jansen
        Dr Black
        Dr Waymour
        Dr Jansen
Sir Philip